# Prove the limit is $e^\alpha$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

> prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+{\alpha\over n}\right)^n=e^\alpha$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+{\alpha\over n}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\left(1+{\alpha\over n}\right)^{n\cdot \alpha^{-1}}\right)^\alpha=e^\alpha$$

Is it valid?

Comment: Maybe. That depends on what sort of things you can use. First, you need to know that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \biggl(1 + \frac{1}{x}\biggr)^x = e$$ holds not only for integer values of $x$, but for arbitrary values of $x$, since $\frac{n}{\alpha}$ is rarely an integer if $n$ is one. Then you need to know some properties of exponentiation with arbitrary exponents, in particular the continuity. If all these things are known and can be used without explicit mention, the argument is fine.

Comment: How do you define $e^\alpha$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are allowed to use the definition of $e$, then yes, you can because if $n \to \infty$, then $\frac{n}{\alpha} \to \infty$ too. If you use CoV, you get the result. Also you need to assume $e^\alpha$ is a continuous function, which allows you the limit interchange.

Comment: What does CoV stand for? It's not "calculus of variations" here, I bet.

Comment: change of variable

Comment: Ah. Makes sense. Thanks.